# Display issues on website after selecting language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Our website](https://www.hollandmarineparts.nl/) has some display issues after selecting a language. Take [This page](https://www.hollandmarineparts.nl/de/) for example. When we view the page in German, the following becomes clear:

- The main slider is no longer able to slide
- The language selector stops working
- The middle section slider is half off the page and no longer able to slide.

I suspect a javascript issue after the language selection is made. Yet all files are loaded correctly. We do not know where to start looking for the issue.

I do not expect an immediate solution, but I hope that someone can point us in the right direction.

Comment: Try open the console and look at the errors. then it give you a freaking good idea about the problem

Comment: I have done so, yet the console does not print any errors for me.

Comment: Kinda easy to spot, it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably mention what technology you are using for the translations. Also the issue seems to be that you are using a sub-folder for each language. Ex:  https://www.hollandmarineparts.nl works but https://www.hollandmarineparts.nl/nl doesn't.

It seems that the routes are broken for when you have a language other than default. (determined from the errors in the browser console)

EDIT: The route to yours `plugins.js` and `scripts.js` is breaking. It prints:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

because it can't find them and it's returning index.html.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer Simeon :) I'm gonna look into this.